# how to get the .child key in an array?

Tags: swift, firebase

I want to take the save all of my blocked user child as a string in my code. But as simple as it might sound I was not able to figure it out.

```
static func block(myself: String, posterUID:  String){
    var blockedUserRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(myself).child("blockedUsers").child(posterUID)
    blockedUserRef.setValue(true)

    var blokedArray:[String] = []
    var handle:DatabaseHandle!

    blockedUserRef = Database.database().reference()
    handle = blockedUserRef.child("blockedUsers").observe(.childAdded, with:{ (DataSnapshot) in
        if let item = DataSnapshot.value as? String{
            blokedArray.append(item)
        }
    })



}
```

I want to take the array of my blocked users go through in for loop and filter them from showing.

```
ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [DataSnapshot]
            else { return completion([]) }

        // 3 filter the user from the array
        let users =
            snapshot
                .flatMap(User.init)
                .filter { $0.uid != currentUser.uid }
```

Here is my firebase:

```
 "users" : {
    "3YLVUDA8YnSuVYUTxv6cvOQPSjm1" : {
       "username" : ""
    },
    "4duY2hhTv5S7sSXtZYBfiP7JBLz1" : {
      "username" : "Love from NYC"
    },
    "58t0M2Fxxhg6GRT96vVbKMFHRKO2" : {
      "blockedUsers" : {
        "4duY2hhTv5S7sSXtZYBfiP7JBLz1" : true,
        "SqarOdPJUydcdV6deXTeIdzkarE2" : true
      },
      "username" : "IStandWithYou"
    },
```

some new ways I am trying I debugged it and it seems that it is not saving it onto the array

```
     ///adedblock
        var blockedUserRef = Database.database().reference().child("users").child(currentUser.uid).child("blockedUsers")


        var blokedArray:[String] = []
        var handle:DatabaseHandle!

        blockedUserRef = Database.database().reference()
        handle = blockedUserRef.child("blockedUsers").observe(.childAdded, with:{ (DataSnapshot) in
            if let item = DataSnapshot.value as? String{
                blokedArray.append(item)
            }
        })

        for user in blokedArray{
            let users =
                snapshot
                    .flatMap(User.init)
                    .filter { $0.uid != user }
        }
```

Comment: "take the save all of my blocked user child as a string" What does that mean?

Comment: Do you want all blocked users from every node? i.e. the blocked users from the 3YL node and also the blocked users from the 4du, 58t, JLJ node etc? Also, along with @matt comment, where do you want to save the string and what do you want in the string. And.... PLEASE post your firebsase structure as text please, no images and you should also include the code you've tried so we can understand your use case.

Comment: @Jay I only want to take my blocked users in an array and then go throw them in for loop and filter them. I edited the code above according to what u said for some reason I was not able to add my firebase as an string

Comment: You can always add text to your question. To get your firebase structure, go to your Firebase Console click the three dots on the right, then export JSON. You can copy and paste from that file.

Comment: @Jay I did it, thanks

Comment: If you can answer my question from above, we can probably help. Do you want all blocked users from all users node or just the blocked users from one users node?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by saving all of the child entries of blockedUsers to an array that will hold all your strings.

To do this, first create an empty array like

```
myList:[string] = []
```

Then, you need to create a reference to your Firebase database like:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
```

You also need a database handle to navigate around your database:

```
var handle:DatabaseHandle!
```

Now, you need to go to your ViewDidLoad function and add code like:

```
ref = Database.database().reference()
    handle = ref?.child("blockedUsers").observe(.childAdded, with:{ (DataSnapshot) in
        if let item = DataSnapshot.value as? String{
            self.myList.append(item)
        }
    })
```

This piece of code is checking whether an entry is added to the child database "blockedUsers", and from that, it is adding whatever was just entered into the array.

Now, you have an array filled with whatever was in the child database, blockedUsers. You can now use the array in a UITableView, or list it in a label.

Hope this helped!

Comment: thanks for the code. I am doing this UserServoce and I don't have a ViewDidL.. in there. Besides this, I wanted to add these in an array of user service so I could then filter the blocked users. I will post a couple of pic and code from what I have done with ur code.Thank u gain

Comment: I added ur code (u can look at my post again) but it seems like it doesn't add to the array. could help me with that please